# Multiple while Loop with multipl query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table and i want to get the highest and lowest selling product. I have so far managed to get the highest selling product and i want the lowest which am unable to get.
The below is the php query that selects product and counts in descending and limit to 1 to get the highest count.
What am unable to do is join the ascending select query so that i can get the lowest selling product.

```
        <th>Today</th>
        <?php
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","inventory");
            
            $query2=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT prod_id, prod_name, price, count(price) as pricee FROM sales_details 
            natural join product /* WHERE date(date_added) = current_date*/ GROUP BY prod_id ORDER BY count(price) DESC LIMIT 1");
            
            $query3=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT prod_id, prod_name, price, count(price) as lowest FROM sales_details 
            natural join product /* WHERE date(date_added) = current_date*/ GROUP BY prod_id ORDER BY count(price) ASC LIMIT 1");
            

            while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
              $price=$row2['pricee'];
              
            while($row3=mysqli_fetch_array($query3)){
              $price2=$row3['lowest'];
            
        ?> 
        <td><?php echo $row2['prod_name'];?>&nbsp;Sold&nbsp;<?php echo $price;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row3['prod_name'];?>&nbsp;Sold&nbsp;<?php echo $price2;?></td>
        <?php}};?>
     </tr>
```

The second while loop is not working, just displays errors

Comment: you have to close the { for the whiles

Comment: and you could UNION ALL both queries so that ypou have only one while and query

Comment: Your result sets only return one row, so I don't see the need for the while loop overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching just 1 record so you can do this outside the while loop. Justo close those loops once you get the values

```
<th>Today</th>
    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","inventory");
        
        $query2=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT prod_id, prod_name, price, count(price) as pricee FROM sales_details 
        natural join product /* WHERE date(date_added) = current_date*/ GROUP BY prod_id ORDER BY count(price) DESC LIMIT 1");
        
        $query3=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT prod_id, prod_name, price, count(price) as lowest FROM sales_details 
        natural join product /* WHERE date(date_added) = current_date*/ GROUP BY prod_id ORDER BY count(price) ASC LIMIT 1");
        

        while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
          $price=$row2['pricee'];
        }

        while($row3=mysqli_fetch_array($query3)){
          $price2=$row3['lowest'];
        }
    ?> 
    <td><?php echo $row2['prod_name'];?>&nbsp;Sold&nbsp;<?php echo $price;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row3['prod_name'];?>&nbsp;Sold&nbsp;<?php echo $price2;?></td>
 </tr>
```

And you can UNION both queries in order to clean your code a bit:

```
<th>Today</th>
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","inventory");
    
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT prod_id, prod_name, price, count(price) as pricee FROM sales_details 
    natural join product /* WHERE date(date_added) = current_date*/ GROUP BY prod_id ORDER BY count(price) DESC LIMIT 1
    UNION
    SELECT prod_id, prod_name, price, count(price) as lowest FROM sales_details 
    natural join product /* WHERE date(date_added) = current_date*/ GROUP BY prod_id ORDER BY count(price) ASC LIMIT 1");
    

    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
        $price=$row2['pricee'];
        $price2=$row2['lowest'];
    }
?> 
<td><?php echo $row2['prod_name'];?>&nbsp;Sold&nbsp;<?php echo $price;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row3['prod_name'];?>&nbsp;Sold&nbsp;<?php echo $price2;?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Since both queries return only one row there's no need for a `while` at all. In your second example using a `while` results in the second row values overwriting the first, so two separate fetches would be easier.

Comment: i think my problem was not closing the whiles......The above answer now works</>